# Upgrading Xcode Project to 3.2

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, upgrade

How would I update my xcode project to 3.2? I need the app delegate of 3.2, but on my current 3.1 project doesn't have them. Please let me know how to do this.

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Xcode 3.2 doesn't have an "app delegate," it's a development tool. Are you saying that you need to update the source code of your project to add an app delegate class?

Comment: Well, when I make a new app in xcode 3.2, there is (name of app)AppDelegate. I want that in my Xcode project as well. It's not only that but I also need the new updates they have.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376644 (even seems to be the same user)

Answer (score 3):

I already told you how to add an application delegate in [my answer on your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375214/application-delegate-cocoa/1375700#1375700). There aren't any other features that would require an “upgrade” of the project.