# Xcode Project Update for 3.2?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, osx-snow-leopard

I have a Xcode project from 3.0, and I want to update it to the 3.2 featues. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 3.2 reads and saves projects from Xcode 2.5 through 3.1.3, and most Xcode 3.2 features (like static analysis, incremental find, new Documentation viewer, etc.) are agnostic to the particular project version.  Open the project, choose Edit Project Settings, and in the General pane set the Project Compatibility to 3.2.

[alt text http://idisk.mac.com/cdespinosa/Public/Project%20Compatibility.png](http://idisk.mac.com/cdespinosa/Public/Project%20Compatibility.png)

There are a few features, like Multiple Project Roots, that will only work in projects that are specifically restricted to Xcode 3.2, and will prevent you from opening that project on earlier versions.